# Recursively merge JSON structures

Tags: java, json

I have n set of json string. How can i merge them into only one in Java?

The latest json override previous information in case of conflict. Arrays are not merged.

## Example

json base :

```
{
    "plank" : {
        "count" : 2,
        "properties" : {
            "type" : "oak",
            "dimensions" : [5.0, 25, 25]
        }
    }
}
```

merge with :

```
{
    "plank" : {
        "count" : 4,
        "properties" : {
            "dimensions" : [5.0, 12.5, 25]
        }
    },
    "scrap" : {
        "count" : 1,
    }
}
```

become :

```
{
    "plank" : {
        "count" : 4,
        "properties" : {
            "type" : "oak",
            "dimensions" : [5.0, 12.5, 25]
        }
    },
    "scrap" : {
        "count" : 1,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing One method that merge JSON recursively.

```
public JSONObject merge(List<JSONObject> objects) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < objects.size() - 1; i++, j++) {
        merge(objects.get(i), objects.get(j));
    }
    return objects.get(objects.size() - 1);
}


private void merge(JSONObject j1, JSONObject j2) {
    Iterator<String> keys = j1.keys();
    Object obj1, obj2;
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String next = keys.next();
        if (j1.isNull(next)) continue;
        obj1 = j1.get(next);
        if (!j2.has(next)) j2.putOpt(next, obj1);
        obj2 = j2.get(next);
        if (obj1 instanceof JSONObject && obj2 instanceof JSONObject) {
            merge((JSONObject) obj1, (JSONObject) obj2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks good but the problem is that it modifies the existing json structures. To be perfect, it should create new merge json structure without modifying the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Jackson library  and convert the JSON string to map first and then merging (iterate through the map and merge).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public JSONObject merge(Stream<JSONObject> jsonObjectStream) {
    JSONObject finalMerged = new JSONObject();
    finalMerged = jsonObjectStream.reduce(finalMerged, this::merge);

    return finalMerged;
}

private JSONObject merge(JSONObject mergedJson, JSONObject jsonToAdd) {
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonToAdd.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        if (!jsonToAdd.isNull(key)) {
            Object itemToMerge = jsonToAdd.get(key);
            // If target object to merge is another json object, we need to see if our existing object
            // has the same key already set, and if so, they need to be merged.
            if ((itemToMerge instanceof JSONObject) && (mergedJson.opt(key) instanceof JSONObject)) {
                itemToMerge = merge(mergedJson.getJSONObject(key), (JSONObject) itemToMerge);
            }
            mergedJson.putOpt(key, itemToMerge);
        }
    }

    return mergedJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library that does this job for you, like [JSON Merge](https://github.com/oswaldobapvicjr/jsonmerge/), available at Maven Central.

You may get the desired result with a single line of code (you may ignore the String declarations if you already have the JSONObjects previously loaded):

```
String jsonBase = "{\n"
            + "    \"plank\" : {\n"
            + "        \"count\" : 2,\n"
            + "        \"properties\" : {\n"
            + "            \"type\" : \"oak\",\n"
            + "            \"dimensions\" : [5.0, 25, 25]\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "}";

String jsonOverride = "{\n"
            + "    \"plank\" : {\n"
            + "        \"count\" : 4,\n"
            + "        \"properties\" : {\n"
            + "            \"dimensions\" : [5.0, 12.5, 25]\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    \"scrap\" : {\n"
            + "        \"count\" : 1,\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "}";

JSONObject result = new JsonMerger<>(JSONObject.class).merge(jsonOverride, jsonBase);
```

**Note:** the first JSON parameter passed to the `merge` method will always have more precedence/importance than the second one in case of key collisions.